# mysql (mariadb) ordering by two columns does not work

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to get answers with ordering by text and timestamp, firs must be answers with text = null, next with text not null ordered by ts, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE user_id = 1279942 ORDER BY text, ts desc;
+----------+---------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+
| id       | user_id | question_id | ts         | text                          | is_new |
+----------+---------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+
| 81187563 | 1279942 |    30918210 | 1487186969 | NULL                          |      0 |
| 81187560 | 1279942 |    30918209 | 1487117018 | NULL                          |      0 |
| 81187559 | 1279942 |    30918208 | 1487116399 | NULL                          |      0 |
| 81187557 | 1279942 |    30918205 | 1487024673 | Jg jg jg                      |      1 |
| 81187555 | 1279942 |    30918205 | 1487022656 | Jg jg jg                      |      1 |
|        7 | 1279942 |    30915697 | 1397915529 | lf                            |      0 |
| 81187535 | 1279942 |    30915687 | 1397047472 | да                            |      0 |
|        8 | 1279942 |    30915697 | 1397990298 | да все ок                     |      0 |
| 81187543 | 1279942 |    30915688 | 1397047582 | Да ничего                     |      0 |
| 81187561 | 1279942 |    30918206 | 1487186497 | Леха, все супер!              |      1 |
| 81187556 | 1279942 |    30918205 | 1487022667 | Оп оп                         |      1 |
| 81187558 | 1279942 |    30918207 | 1487186977 | Последний ответ               |      1 |
| 81187562 | 1279942 |    30917194 | 1487186733 | ТЕСТОВЫЙ ОТВЕТ                |      1 |
|     1537 | 1279942 |    30917195 | 1413380315 | фыв                           |      0 |
| 81187547 | 1279942 |    30915691 | 1397048820 | щл                            |      0 |
+----------+---------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

on the 4th row must be answer with id 81187558. Who know what can cause it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but you could probably use something like this to order in the fashion you're after:

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE user_id = 1279942 
    ORDER BY ISNULL(text) DESC, ts DESC;
```

Note that `ISNULL()` returns `0` if the value is not null, and `1` if it is. Thus by sorting that in a descending order first, we place all of the records where `text` is `NULL` at the top. This creates two buckets that all share a `ISNULL` value. So the remainder will be sorted only by `ts` since `ISNULL` are all `0`.

Your original approach sorts by `text` first, and then for each bucket of shared `text` values, it sorts those internally by `ts`.

Comment: Wow.. It works, but what is the difference between using isnull and just ordering by column?